# Change property of Maven POM

Tags: maven, plugins, properties, pom.xml, mojo

I need to change a property of my `pom.xml`.

I searched and I didnt found any plugin that changes properties in the `pom.xml`. So I decided to write my own pPlugin. Is there any way to persist the changes I make in my Mojo? Or does someone know a plugin who can change property values of a `pom.xml`?

```
@Mojo(name = "propertyVersion")
public class propertyVersionMojo extends AbstractMojo {
    @Parameter(property = "propertyVersion.property")
    private String property;

    @Parameter(property = "propertyVersion.value")
    private String value;
    @Parameter(property = "propertyVersion.project", defaultValue = "${project}")
    private MavenProject project;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        System.out.println("Setting property " + property);
        System.out.println("to value" + value);
        project.getProperties().setProperty(property, value);
    }
}
```

My plugin works, but does not change the new value to the POM.

Thx ;)

Comment: First question: What do you _really_ want to achieve? Why would you like to change a user set property in the build process?

Comment: i use properties to define versions of some dependencies. for me it was the easiest way to group versions of dependencies

Comment: Use dependencyManagement or use the [versions-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/)